# SQL Check Constraint on column and Ignores default value, errors out

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

SQL Server 2008
Here is the error msg i got.
error: Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1 
The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK__S_ODS_L2__*ACTIV*_7A5F6E76". The conflict occurred in database "SourceDB", table "dbo.Datatbl", column 'ACTIVE_FLAG'.

But this column has default value as "Y".
Here is the table script
    USE [SourceDB]
    GO

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Datatbl](
    [BATCH_NB] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [RCRD_NB] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [STS_CD] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ENTR_DT] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [COMMENTS_TXT] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [ACTIVE_FLAG] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [Err_CD] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [Source_Fld_Name] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Source_Fld_Val] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Error_Desc] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [ISRT_USR] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [UPDT_USR] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [ISRT_DT] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [UPDT_DT] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ProcessDate] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Datatbl]  WITH CHECK ADD CHECK  (([ACTIVE_FLAG]='N' OR     [ACTIVE_FLAG]='Y'))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Datatbl] ADD  DEFAULT ('Y') FOR [ACTIVE_FLAG]
GO
```

Here is my insert query

```
INSERT INTO Datatbl 
(BATCH_NB,
RCRD_NB,
STS_CD,
ENTR_DT,
COMMENTS_TXT,
ACTIVE_FLAG,
Err_CD,
Source_Fld_Name,
Source_Fld_Val,
Error_Desc,
ISRT_USR,
UPDT_USR,
ISRT_DT,
UPDT_DT,
ProcessDate)        
Values (
46401, --Batch
'308', --Rcrd_NB
'1', --STS_CD
'2014-03-07 15:03:11.000000', -- Entr_DT
'Comments test', --comments
'', -- Active_flag, see no value here
'',--Err_Cd
'',--Src_Fld_Nm
'',--Src_Fld_Val
'Error description ', --ErrDesc
'${user_id}', --Inst User
'', --Updt User
'2014-03-07 15:03:11.958578', --ISRT_DT
'',--UPDT_DT
'01/15/2014') -- Processdate
```

This used to work fine until recently but somehow isn't working.
I'm not sure something changed on database side or maybe data is the problem here.

Any thoughts, Pls. let me know.

Thanks,
Cindy!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the query is that you have added a value of '' for ACTIVE_FLAG, When you are passing a value to a column, default value would not be taken.

If you want to insert default value into the column :- 
(1) Just remove the column and its value from the iNSERT command 
OR 
(2) replace that with a DEFAULT key word, ( '' is not equivalent to 'Y' or 'N', that is the root cause )

```
INSERT INTO Datatbl 
(BATCH_NB,
RCRD_NB,
STS_CD,
ENTR_DT,
COMMENTS_TXT,
ACTIVE_FLAG,
Err_CD,
Source_Fld_Name,
Source_Fld_Val,
Error_Desc,
ISRT_USR,
UPDT_USR,
ISRT_DT,
UPDT_DT,
ProcessDate)        
Values (
46401, --Batch
'308', --Rcrd_NB
'1', --STS_CD
'2014-03-07 15:03:11.000000', -- Entr_DT
'Comments test', --comments
--'', -- Active_flag, see no value here
DEFAULT, -- value replaced with default
'',--Err_Cd
'',--Src_Fld_Nm
'',--Src_Fld_Val
'Error description ', --ErrDesc
'${user_id}', --Inst User
'', --Updt User
'2014-03-07 15:03:11.958578', --ISRT_DT
'',--UPDT_DT
'01/15/2014') -- Processdate
```